# Adding SSL Certificate in Azure Mobile App caused Notifcation Hub to fail

Tags: wcf, ssl-certificate, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I was making a call using Azure Mobile App's NotificationHubClient and using Firebase (gcm) to notify my Android device using : SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync call. And I'm getting exception : "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

My setup :

- Azure Mobile App running the Quick Start sample backend and Xamarin
  Form mobile app
- Notification Hub setup with F1 free tier
- The backend from Quick Start sample is modified to call WCF on
  another server on premise. This currently secured by TLS certificate

> ```
> <bindings>
>   <basicHttpBinding>
>     <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
>       <security mode="Transport">
>             <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
>       </security>
>     </binding>
>   </basicHttpBinding>
> </bindings>
> ```

- Self Signed Certificate that's required by WCF was uploaded to the
  Mobile App, and set to the Service Reference rs :

> ```
> rs.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
>                                    StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
>                                    StoreName.My,
>                                    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
>                                    "<thumbprintforthecertificate>");
> ```

- At this point everything was working except the above SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync that works only once after I restarted the Azure Mobile App. After that it failed with the exception above.

I searched SO and Microsoft docs, and there's no question or answer regarding my problem.

What I tried :

- In the Application Setting of the Mobile App : blank out the value for WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES. This works for the notification, but my WCF call failed

  - Tried using FirebaseNet by tiagomtotti. This opened up other errors for me - nuget dependency problem
  - Look for any settings in the resources.azure.com, but nothing in that effect

Have anybody had the error when using certificate in the Mobile App and try to run a notification?

Comment: It is a non issue. See my comment on the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from people having problem with Azure service bus

[Service Bus Relay Certificate Trust Chain Verification Error](http://geekswithblogs.net/michaelstephenson/archive/2013/07/17/153435.aspx)

It's a different exception, but it's a workaround that works for me. In the backend ASP.Net config file you have to add :

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.X509RevocationMode" value="NoCheck"/>    
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Well, false hope. It only worked because I re-published it and works only the first time, it failed consistently afterward. Still looking for answer :(

Comment: It turned out that my problem is with a helper class I implemented (PermissiveCertificatePolicy), and RemoteCertValidate method was hit several times, and one of them picked up certificate from "CN=notificationhub.windows.net". I just had to permit this. WARNING! this is for testing only, not recommended for production